# Creating backups of iOS app IPAs on Mac

Tags: iphone, itunes, ios-appstore, apple-configurator, ios

I am trying to copy individual apps from my iPhone over to my Mac so I can restore them after a wipe through Apple Configurator 2. These apps are no longer available on the App Store (Infinity Blade triology), so downloading them after restoring an iCloud backup is not possible.

With older versions of iTunes I was able to back up apps to my Mac, so I could reinstall them again.

Is there any way how I can achieve this on macOS Catalina or newer?

Comment: There are other apps that can do this. I have iMazing but I believe iExplore also will allow you to back up your apps and even restore them. They are both a kind of (forgive the phrase...) power users iTunes for managing your iPhone.

Comment: iMazing cannot.  And most likely now that we have app-thinning, you don't want to do this anyway.  Regarding Infinity Blade, it doesn't appear in your purchases?

Comment: Infinity blade was removed from my purchases with the cancellation of Epic's developer account.

Comment: Based on some similar juggling I did last year to rescue an old app, I think you need to already have the ipa. Then you can drop it to Configurator & load it to the phone. I can't see any way to use Configurator to grab an ipa from the phone.